# JSTL to Java Script array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jstl

I am trying to put array from JSTL for loop to an array in JS

```
<c:forEach items="${defaultWishList}" var="eachItem">
    ${eachItem.getItem().getId()};
    ${eachItem.getItem().getName()};
</c:forEach>
```

and put each row in :

```
var ar = new Array();
```

Now I tried the following way which is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ar = new Array();
var aaa="";
var bbb="";
<c:forEach items="${defaultWishList}" var="eachItem">
    aaa = ""+${eachItem.getItem().getId()};
    bbb = ""+${eachItem.getItem().getName()};
    ar.push({
    F : aaa,
    L : bbb
    });
</c:forEach>
</script>
```

Is it possible to do this. If yes then how??

Comment: If course it's possible, JSP is just a template. That said, why bother doing it like this? Expose the value as json, and do that conversion outside of the view.

Comment: how to do that? could you pleas write me the code??

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work - you have to access the JSTL object using its syntax - i.e `${eachItem.item.id}` and not `${eachItem.getItem().getId()}`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var ar = new Array();

<c:forEach items="${defaultWishList}" var="eachItem">
    ar.push({
    F : '${eachItem.item.id}',
    L : '${eachItem.item.name}'
    });
</c:forEach>
</script>
```